# ¿Cómo evitar que el texto se deseleccione al primer click fuera?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Trato de hacer un editor de texto enriquecido pero al seleccionar la parte del texto a cambiar y presionar la herramienta para cambiar sus estilos este se deselecciona.

Me explico: cuando un usuario seleccione en el editor un texto ***éste queda seleccionado*** mientras el usuario decide que acción hacer sobre él.

Intenté:

```
const pizzarra = document.getElementById('pizzarra')

pizzarra.onclick = e =>{
  e.preventDefault() 
}
```

pero esto no funciona. Al tocar cualquier parte fuera del texto seleccionado, éste pierde su selección y no puedo realizar acciones sobre éste.

¿Alguna idea de como guardar la selección o evitar que se deseleccione?

Comment: Ahora si es claro del porque lo necesitas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te pego un ejemplo muy básico de un editor WYSIWYG:

```js
const negrita = document.getElementById('negrita');
const cursiva = document.getElementById('cursiva');

negrita.onclick = e => {
  document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
}

cursiva.onclick = e => {
  document.execCommand('italic', false, null);
}
```

```css
#pizarra { width: 10em; height: 8em; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<div id="pizarra" contenteditable="true">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
</div>

<input id="negrita" type="button" value="Negrita"/>
<input id="cursiva" type="button" value="Cursiva"/>
```

Aquí hay dos puntos importantes:

- Para que el elemento que sea editable tiene que tener el atributo `contenteditable` a true (en mi caso la pizarra).
- En cada manejador de evento, se llama `execCommand` que ya hace la parte de gestionar la negrita, cursiva, etc. Hay una lista de comandos disponibles que te dejo en los enlaces más abajo:

Más info:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Commands
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Comment: Gracias! intentaba con lo mismo pero en vez del input un span y veo que con el inout button no se pierde lo selecionado. Gracias de verdad me sirvio tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar que se quite lo seleccionado deberás usar el onmousedown.

Entiendo que el elemento 'pizzarra' no es donde se esta seleccionando el texto, con  la función que estamos poniendo en el onmousedown también estamos evitando que se pueda seleccionar texto en dicho elemento.

Deberás poner dicha función solo en el elemento donde se deciden las acciones que puede hacer el usuario.

```
const pizzarra = document.getElementById('pizzarra');

pizzarra.onmousedown = e =>{
  e.preventDefault() 
}
```